# How gravity was implemented in UNITY 3D game engine

Tags: unity-game-engine

The basic of gravity was implemented using the collider. Could you explain how the gravity was implemented.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you be a little more specific what you are asking?

Comment: Pretty sure Unity uses Physx for 3D physics (and Box2D for 2D physics).

Comment: Curious, why is Unreal Engine 4 being tagged if you are making a statement about Unity?

Answer (score 1):

For 3D physics, Unity uses PhysX, which is an Nvidia developed, propriety physics system. You can learn much more about it from Nvidia.

Here are the docs: https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/physx/guide/Manual/Index.html

Unity used an older version of this prior to their latest 2018.3 betas.